# Sqlite pode funcionar totalmente offline?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Estou precisando guardar os meus alarmes de maneira que depois do dispositivo ser reiniciado sejam colocados novamente em funcionamento.

O problema é que recebo todos eles através da minha base de dados em `mysql`.

O que me fez pensar que talvez seria boa ideia guardar em uma base de dados offline para depois ser possível colocar novamente os horários a funcionar.

Surgiram então duas perguntas:

1. `Sqlite` consegue funcionar totalmente offline?
2. Se sim, se o utilizador limpar a cache ou os dados. O que acontece com essa base de dados?

Comment: SQLite quase sempre é para funcionar offline. Online dá, mas é exceção.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Sqlite consegue funcionar totalmente offline?

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) é uma biblioteca em *linguagem C* que implementa um banco de dados SQL embutido. Programas que usam a biblioteca SQLite podem ter acesso a banco de dados SQL sem executar um processo SGBD separado.

SQLite não é uma biblioteca cliente usada para conectar com um grande servidor de banco de dados, *mas sim o próprio servidor*. [A biblioteca SQLite lê e escreve diretamente para e do arquivo do banco de dados no disco](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), ou seja ele trabalha totalmente offline.

> 2. Se sim, se o utilizador limpar a cache ou os dados. O que acontece com essa base de dados?

Os dados salvos no banco de dados `SQLite` não são limpados (deletados), pelo gerenciador de memória, somente procedimentos ou rotinas que acessem os dados podem fazer essa alteração.

Veja também:

[Sqlite-sync](http://sqlite-sync.com/) é uma estrutura para sincronizar dados entre um banco de dados SQLite e um banco de dados MS SQL / MySQL. Com este quadro sua aplicação pode trabalhar completamente off-line (Modo Avião), em seguida, executar uma sincronização automática bidirecional quando uma conexão com a internet se torna disponível.

[Aqui](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&u=https://github.com/rla/sql-sync&usg=ALkJrhjnzWWhi2xckJmAOp-44umJMtcsJQ) tem um projeto com essa arquitetura como exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar o banco(sqlite), colocar na pasta Assets do seu projeto e usar o banco offline tranquilamente.

Por exemplo, você pode usar DB Browser http://sqlitebrowser.org para o criar e preencher o .bd, e, além disso, você também pode usar essa biblioteca aqui https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper pra te ajudar a ler o banco.

Mas porque você não usa simplesmente um arquivo XML ou JSON pra guardar esses dados? Não seria menos trabalhoso?

Comment: Como é que eu crio um Json para poder ser acedido offline  realmente é uma melhor solução e json é algo que eu sei trabalhar se conseguir explicar ficaria agradecido , relembrando mesmo que o utilizador limpe os dados o json tem que continuar com os dados guardados

Comment: Arquivo XML ou JSON são útil mais para trafico de dados pela rede, não como uso de base de dados.

Comment: As preferencias do usuário, por exemplo, são salvas em um .XML.
http://codetheory.in/saving-user-settings-with-android-preferences/, vale uma leitura.